# Does TDengine support deleting data functions?

Tags: time-series, tdengine

Does TDengine support data deletion? Or a more general question: does time-series database usually support data deletion functions?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can set *KEEP* variable when creating database:

```
CREATE DATABASE [IF NOT EXISTS] db_name [KEEP keep] [DAYS days] [UPDATE 1]
```